# Sub-setting to find the anomaly

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

In a data frame, I am trying to look for data points that are more than (threshold * s.d.) away from mean. The `dim` of the data frame is as follows:

```
[1] 4032    4
```

To find the data points for the above condition, I did:

```
df$mean = rollapply(df$value, width = 2, FUN = mean, align = "right", fill = "extend")

df$sd = rollapply(df$value, width = 2, FUN = sd,  align = "right", fill = "extend")
```

After the above the `head(df)` looks like:

```
            timestamp  value   mean        sd
2007-03-14 1393577520 37.718 38.088 0.5232590
2007-03-15 1393577220 38.458 38.088 0.5232590
2007-03-16 1393576920 37.912 38.185 0.3860803
2007-03-17 1393576620 40.352 39.132 1.7253405
2007-03-18 1393576320 38.474 39.413 1.3279465
2007-03-19 1393576020 39.878 39.176 0.9927779
```

To find the datapoints:

```
anomaly = df[df$value > abs((threshold*df$sd + df$mean) | 
                                (df$mean - threshold*df$sd)),]
```

Is above the correct way to find data points that are more than (threshold * s.d.) away from mean. The reason I am suspicious is that `dim` of `anomaly` is same as that of `df`.

Comment: Why are you using `rollapply` here? Maybe you just want `anomaly = df[abs(df$value - mean(df$value)) > threshold * sd(df$value),]`. When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions

Comment: @MrFlick It returns zero rows.

Comment: @MrFlick Updated the `head(df)`

Comment: @Jatt it could then be that there are no anomalies in your dataset. Alternatively you could also try something similar to MrFlick's answer: `anomaly = df[abs(df$value - df$mean) > threshold * sd(df$sd),]`

Comment: @MikeH. This gave 3 rows. Could you explain what does the statement `data points that are more than (threshold * s.d.) away from mean.` really mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it

```
# creating some dummy data
m <- matrix(runif(16128,-1,1), ncol = 4)

tresh <- .004+1
m[which(abs(m-mean(m)) > tresh*sd(m), arr.ind = T)]
```

Where `m` denotes your matrix (or your column `value` depending on whichever you take the mean/sd) and `tresh` your treshold.

**Update** Here are the first couple of entries of my result:

```
dat <- df$value[which(abs(df$value-mean(df$value)) > tresh*sd(df$value))]
head(dat)
[1] 51.846 48.568 44.986 49.108 53.404 46.314
```

Comment: what does `arr.T` mean?

Comment: `arr.ind = TRUE`, it means that which returns the `array index`, i.e. it makes `which` say "in row x, col y there is a match" instead of "elment number X is a match". (But it actually is not needed here, so you can just leave it out)

Comment: The data I am trying on gives out 0 rows. I am sure there are anomalies in the data.

Comment: Here is the csv I am trying : http://www.sharecsv.com/s/af385df6de4421fd6094fc758f2d9a3b/ec2_cpu_utilization_5f5533.csv

Comment: Works perfectly fine when I do `dat <- df$value[which(abs(df$value-mean(df$value)) > tresh*sd(df$value))]`. See the edit for my result `dat`.

Comment: Okay. I am trying for tresh=4 and gives out 2 results. Earlier I was trying like `p = tresh * sd(df$value)
m = mean(df$value)
df[df$value > p+m,]` Is it incorrect than what you suggested?

Comment: Of course, the result depends on `tresh`. The problem with `df$value > p+m` is that you do not take into account the instances where `m-df$value > p`, i.e. `df$value < m-p`

Comment: Is there a way I could use `rolling mean` and `rolling standard deviation` in place of global mean and sd?

Comment: @Jatt I am not familiar with `rolling mean / sd`. If these are functions then you could probably just swap them for `mean / sd`